# How to solve this ? Can't find my mistake

Tags: c

My problem:

> [Error] cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' for argument '2' to 'void subcategory(int, float, float)'

My problem:

[image: c program]

C program codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void subcategory(int num,float emission,float pollution); 
int main() 
{
int n; 
int category_value; 
int sub_category;  
int i=0; 
float emission=0; 
float pollution=0;

for(i;i<=n;i++)
{ 
printf("Please select a Category by entering a relvenat value- 1.Building 2.Vehicle 3.Bike"); 
scanf("%d",&category_value); 
subcategory(category_value,&emission,&pollution);
}
printf("Total Co2 emission %f \n Total Air pollutants %f \n",emission,pollution); 
return 0; 
} 


void subcategory(int num ,float w,float emission,float pollution)
{ 
int num1;
if(num==1)
{ 
printf("Please select a subcategory 1.smallhouse/flat 2.medium house 3.large house"); 
scanf("%d",&num1);
printf("Enter weight");
scanf("%f",&w);
if(num1==1)
{ 
pollution=w*3.1;emission=w*1.58; 
} 
else if(num1==2)
{ 
emission=w*2.53;pollution=w*5.1; 
} 
else
{ 
emission=w*3.69; pollution=w*7.5; 
} 
}


else if(num==2)
{ 
printf("Please select a subcategory 1.small car 2.medium car 3.large car");
scanf("%d",&num1);
printf("Enter weight");
scanf("%f",&w); 
if(num1==1)
{ 
emission=w*37;pollution=w*21.4; 
} 
else if(num1==2)
{ 
emission=w*37;pollution=w*21.4; 
} 
else
{ 
emission=w*34;pollution=w*26.2;
} 
} 


else
{ 
printf("Please select a subcategory 1.standrad 2.cruisers 3.sport"); 
scanf("%d",&num1);
printf("Enter weight");
scanf("%f",&w); 
if(num1==1)
{ 
pollution=w*0.96;emission=w*0.3; 
} 
else if(num1==2)
{ 
emission=w*0.91;pollution=w*1.74; 
} 
else
{ 
emission=w*1.25;pollution=w*2.72; 
} 
} 
}
```

How can I repair this code?

Comment: You should read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to learn how to do this.

Comment: `subcategory(category_value,&emission,&pollution);` The function doesn't expect pointers, so don't pass them. Remove the `&`. It looks like in the function you might expect the changes made to those parameters to be persistent. In that case, you will need the pointers, you will need to change the function signature, and you will need to adjust the code inside the function to deal with dereferencing the pointers.

Comment: Thanks I remove the & in subcategory(category_value,&emission,&pollution);  Then another error appear "[Error] ld returned 1 exit status"

Answer (score 0):

There were two errors in your code:

1. No pointer arguments are expected by the function `void subcategory(int, float, float)`. They only expects a simple value.

**Solution:** Just remove the ampersands in line number 16.

2. You'll get `ld returns 1 exit code` due to:

   undefined reference to subcategory(int, float, float)

   You're passing only three arguments in line 16, but the function definition is structured to accept four, i.e. `void subcategory(int, float, float, float)` not `int, float, float` only.

**Solution:** Either you need to pass four values from line 16 or remove one of the parameters from the function definition to accept three arguments.

**Don't forget to change the function prototype as same as the function definition located at line 2.**

After that, you should get no errors.